# Android, Retrofit 2: How to make calls every 5 second?

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2

this is my code:

```
 private void getUserData(){
    //create Retrofit instance
    Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create());

    Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();

    //get client & call object for the request
    APIService userService = retrofit.create(APIService.class);

    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("device_id", Utils.GetDeviceID(DashboardActivity.this));

    Call call = userService.getUser(map);

    //execute network request
    call.enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) {
            if(response.isSuccessful() && response.body() != null){
                response.body();
                UserDataManager.$().setUserDataResponse(new com.google.gson.Gson().toJson(response.body()));
                if(UserDataManager.$().getUserData() != null){
                    Log.d(TAG, "USER ID: " + UserDataManager.$().getUserData().getId());
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}
```

Question: How can i call this method every 5 second, to check is the new data coming from backend or not?

Will be glad for suggestions and hints, thanks

Comment: You should have a look to [rxjava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava)

Comment: you make service for calling api in 5 sec.

Answer (score 5):

RxAndroid will be very useful in this case. You can create loop like this

```
Subscription subscription = Observable.interval(1000, 5000, 
 TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(new Action1<Long>() {
            public void call(Long aLong) {
                // here is the task that should repeat
            }
        });
```

If you want to stop the loop just call

```
subscription.unsubscribe()
```

Comment: Action1 has been renamed Consumer in Retrofit 2.

Comment: @QuentinRufin I think you meant to say that Action1 has been renamed to Consumer in RxJava3 not in Retrofit.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Handler` to achieve making call every 5 seconds.

```
boolean shouldStopLoop = false;
Handler mHandler = new Handler();

Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        getUserData();
        if (!shouldStopLoop) {
            mHandler.postDelayed(this, 5000);
        }
    }
};
```

and call `mHandler.post(runnable);` to start the call.

Comment: For now i have that functionality implemented, but not sure if this solution is correct

Comment: Yes, I think polling every 5 seconds to server to check for new data is not good decision. It's much better if the server can push notification to the app when new data is available.

Comment: yes, i think so too, so do you have any ideas how can i achieve that kind of solution uasing Android as Front and PHP, mysql as Backend?

Comment: One solution is to use FCM the other is Web Socket.

Answer (score 1):

**workmanager**  will help you check the [document](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/)

Comment: The OP wants to schedule his work every 5 seconds, but the `WorkManager` docs say, `Periodic work has a minimum interval of 15 minutes.`
https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/work/PeriodicWorkRequest

Answer (score 0):

```
Completable.timer(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(this::doYourThing, this::onError))
```

But a better option would be to ask your backend developer to send a firebase notification in case of a data change since Network calls are expensive operations.